# Why is the derivative of Ln(x) equal to 1/x with no domain restricted?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

When we get the antiderivative of 1/x we put a absolute value for Ln|x| to change the domain so the domains are equal to each other. But my question is then why do we not do this for the derivative of Ln(x)?

Comment: because $\ln(x)$ is defined for $x\in (0,\infty )$ only.

Comment: Now if you were asking about the derivative of $\ln(|x|)$...

Comment: @Surb I still do not really understand because ln(x) is defined for x∈(0,∞) only, so should'nt that mean 1/x should be defined for x∈(0,∞) only?

Comment: @GoldenBoy Of course, the derivative is only defined in $(0, \infty)$. What Surb means is that the absolute value is not necessary at all, as we already have $x > 0$.

Comment: Note that even if $x<0$, the derivative of $\ln(x)$ (now the *complex-valued* logarithm) is still $\frac1x$ because $\ln(x)=\ln|x|+i\arg(x)=\ln|x|-i\pi$.

Comment: Technically, $\ln x$ is an anti-derivative when $x<0,$ it's just that the constant difference from $\ln|x|$ is imaginary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, the natural domain of the derivative $f'(x)$ of the function $f(x)$ is all points $a$ *in the domain of $f$* for which the limit
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$
exists. The usual convention is that if we do not specify the domain of a function, then we mean its natural domain.

Now, you are correct that we are sometimes a little sloppy. The function $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ has natural domain all nonzero real numbers. The function $f(x)=\ln(x)$ has natural domain all *positive* real numbers. The function
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\ln x) = f'(x)$$
will have domain "all positive real numbers for which the corresponding limit exists." As it happens, that limit exists for all positive real numbers, and its value at $a$ is $\frac{1}{a}$. So when we write
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\ln x) = \frac{1}{x}$$
we are implicitly restricting our formula to only those values of $x$ in which *everything* written in the formula makes sense, which in this case is just $x\in (0,\infty)$.

If we were to say "the derivative of $f(x) = \ln(x)$ is $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$", this would be a little sloppy and not quite accurate, as you note. We really should say "the derivative of $f(x) = \ln(x)$ is $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}, x\gt 0$". But we usually elide that last part and assume it is clear from context: that because we are mentioning "derivative of $\ln(x)$", it will be understood that we only mean this assertion to hold for $x$ in appropriate domain.

So what you are observing is an instance in which what we actually say is not *quite* right, but most people are expected to understand that what we *mean* is accurate, once you unpack all the unsaid things.

(As it happens, the function $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, with no restrictions, *is* the derivative of the function $f(x)=\ln|x|$, which is defined for all $x\neq 0$. )